# How to clear Query History from Big Query Console?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to clear the Query History from BigQuery console.
also let me know if their is any possibility that i can clear the failed query result from the console.Let me know is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to clear results from the query history. We've considered adding a 'show only successful queries' flag, but it has been a low priority feature request.